# how to get id of any control using javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have an html page with various textbox and button

then I added this javascript

```
window.onload = function () {
  window.addEventListener('click', function (evt) {
    alert(this.id);
  }, false);
};
```

my goal is to return the ID of the control clicked by the user (as an alert)?
eventually I will add more to this. but as an alert is ok for now. Thank you

Comment: right now just as alert.. alert (the id of the button you clicked is ... txtbutton1 ) <-- something like that..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the [`target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target) of the event. Here's a runnable sample:

```js
window.onload = function () {
  window.addEventListener('click', function (evt) {
    alert(evt.target.id);
  }, false);
};
```

```html
<input id="button" type="button" value="button" />
<input id="text" type="text" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You have added eventListener to the window object.So "this"keyword refers windows object and not your buttons.check for ev.srcElement

```
window.onload = function () {
  window.addEventListener('click', function (evt) {
    alert(evt.srcElement.id);
  }, false);
};
```